# Avoid linear cost of append/3 in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

Let's assume that we're reading from standard input and building a list of all the lines that have been read.  In the end, we need to display those lines, separated by commas.

```
go:-
    prompt(_, ''),
    processInput([ ], Lines),
    findall(_, (member(L, Lines), write(L), write(',')), _),
    nl.

processInput(LinesSoFar, Lines):-
    read_line_to_codes(current_input, Codes),
    processInput(Codes, LinesSoFar, Lines).

processInput(Codes, LinesSoFar, Lines):-
    ( Codes \= end_of_file
    ->
        atom_codes(Line, Codes),
        append(LinesSoFar, [ Line ], LinesSoFar1),  % <---- append/3 - O(n)
        processInput(LinesSoFar1, Lines)
    ;
        Lines = LinesSoFar ).
```

The issue w/ this code is that the `append` call in `processInput/3` costs us O(n).  How can we avoid this cost & still let our predicate be tail-recursive (because we may be reading a lot of lines from standard input)?

It occurred to me that we could replace the `append` with the following.

```
LinesSoFar1 = [ Line | LinesSoFar ],
```

And we could reverse the list before displaying it.  But that seems hacky.  Is there a better way?

Comment: It may seem hacky to you know, but it is the Prolog way of doing this. If you do it right, it preserves logical semantics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not consider the solution you propose (prepending list elements, then reversing the list at the end) "hacky". gusbro's solution with explicit difference lists is OK as well. I think the most elegant way is to use DCG notation (an implicit interface to difference lists), i.e., use a DCG that describes the list of lines:

```
read_lines -->
        { read_line_to_codes(current_input, Codes) },
        (   { Codes == end_of_file } -> []
        ;   { atom_codes(Line, Codes) },
            [Line],
            read_lines
        ).
```

Usage: `phrase(read_lines, Lines)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a semi instantiated structure.
Check this code:

```
append_init(Marker-Marker).

append_end(L-[I|NMarker], I, L-NMarker).

append_finish(L-[], L).
```

You start by 'initializing' the semi-instantiated structure by calling **append_init(L)**.
Then you can add elements at the end of the list by calling **append_end(L, Item, NewList)**.
When you have finished adding elements you call **append_finish(L, List)** to get the final, fully-instantiated list.

Example:

```
example(NL):-
  append_init(L), 
  append_end(L, a, L1), 
  append_end(L1, b, L2), 
  append_end(L2, c, L3), 
  append_finish(L3, NL).

?- example(L).
L = [a, b, c].
```