# curly brackets { } in DCG

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am starting to learn how to use DCGs. I was wondering what curly braces `{...}` are used for? When (and when not) are they required? For example:

```
read_lines -->
  { read_line_to_codes(current_input, Codes) } ,
  (
    { Codes == end_of_file } -> []
  ;
    { atom_codes(Line, Codes) } ,
    [Line],
    read_lines
  ) .
```

provided in response to this question: [Avoid linear cost of append/3 in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279697/avoid-linear-cost-of-append-3-in-prolog/6282975#6282975)

Comment: http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse33

Answer (score 4):

In a DCG rule, the {}'s are used for encapsulating Prolog goals, otherwise those would be interpreted as non-terminals.